# Single Broadcast receiver for all activities in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, network-connection

I have written a class which extends Broadcast receiver in my application.The class is for checking the network connectivity status.What I want is, need to get notified when connection is lost from all the activities using the same class,even if the application is performing some other task.Is there any listener for this

And also where should I unregister.

Please do help me.This is my code

```
public class NetworkBroadcastListner extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context getContext;
public NetworkBroadcastListner(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    getContext = context;
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(
            ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    context.registerReceiver(NetworkBroadcastListner.this, filter1);

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    try {
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext, "Network Connections Unavailable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext, "Network Connections Unavailable",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to  Network Connection Changes through this call and send message to other Activities , other Activities can listen to these messages through Handlers.

You can unregister when your Application Exits.

Read Message and Handler Concept [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: How can I pass the message to other activity.